# Issue writing XML using TextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have tried writing XML using a Textwriter, but I've discovered that I can't write characters < > ' " & to that file.

The class I wrote is as follows:

```
public void Write_File(rss r, string fileName)//-- rss here is a class I built in other place
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rss));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path + fileName);//-- path is directory path to save xml file
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, r);
    textWriter.Close();            
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: You description is not very helpful to locate the error.

Comment: use HtmlEncode to encode string

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot. C# converts such chars:

```
< to &lt; 
> to &gt;
& to &amp;
```

If it will be allowed, you could destroy your XML. If you need to add tags, you cannot simply use serializer. You need to build document using code for example form [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the `System.Web` assembly in your project and leverage the `HttpUtility` class to encode your string like this:

```
public void Write_File(rss r, string fileName)//-- rss here is a class I built in other place
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rss));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path + fileName);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(r));
    textWriter.Close();            
}
```

**and I can only assume you have overriden the `ToString` method of `rss` to return an XML string here because there's no other way you'd be getting a string there.**

Comment: trouble this is HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(r) require r is System.String of type. But r this is an instance of rss class. I tried but it not allowed. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Phan, did you override the ToString method of the RSS class though? If so, try calling ToString on the object when calling HtmlEncode